# check if the words in the message exist in the table

Tags: mysql

I have to write a mysql query with which i have to pass a text message to check if any words in the message are existing in the table

```
Table 
id       words
 1       arse
 2       ball
 3       sex
```

string = "Cricket is a bat and ball game played between two teams of 11 players each on a field at the centre of which is a rectangular 22-yard-long pitch. The game is played by 120 million players in many countries, making it the world's second most popular sport.[1][2][3] Each team takes its turn to bat, attempting to score runs, while the other team fields. Each turn is known as an innings     "

Is it possible to pass the whole string in "like" opt?There are about 1000 words in the table that are to be blocked and checked.
I want to check that does the given string include any words from this table 
If yes then i want the count of words that match this table data.

checked many post.but they have suggested the below opt 
eg

```
select * from table where column like '%Cricket%' or column like '%is%'
...
```

which is slow and not feasible 
is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JOIN ON LIKE`:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(id INT, post VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO posts
SELECT 1, 'Cricket is a bat and ball game played between two teams of 11 players each on a field at the centre of which is a rectangular 22-yard-long pitch. The game is played by 120 million players in many countries, making it the world''s second most popular sport.[1][2][3] Each team takes its turn to bat, attempting to score runs, while the other team fields. Each turn is known as an innings ';

CREATE TABLE words(id INT, word VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO words
SELECT 1 , 'arse' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'ball' UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'sex';
```

Query:

```
SELECT w.word, COUNT(*) AS `occ`
FROM posts p
JOIN words w
 ON p.post LIKE CONCAT('%', w.word, '%')
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY w.word
ORDER BY occ DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a588b/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ word  ║ occ ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ ball  ║   1 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```